# What is ~= in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using jQuery and twitter boootstap with rails. Recently I have found the **bootstrap.js.coffee** file with the below content

```
jQuery ->
  $("a[rel~=popover], .has-popover").popover()
  $("a[rel~=tooltip], .has-tooltip").tooltip()
```

My question is what does this `~=` means?

Sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: Sort of is after you visit this page: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: [Word Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

Comment: The question itself is valid, not reading the manual though is silly

Comment: @charlietfl Valid or not, it shows no research effort, and it is not useful. This is what downvotes are for.

Comment: @meagar I guess what I really meant to say was... *asking yourself the question is valid*. Always amazes me how people come here to ask what they can look up themselves quicker

Comment: @vee Thanks .. Got my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this page: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> **Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~="value"]** Selects elements that
>   have the specified attribute with **a value containing a given word,
>   delimited by spaces**.

By this definition `$('a[rel~=popover]')`:

1. `<a rel="onepopoverover" ...>` would not match
2. `<a rel="one popover over" ...>` would match
3. `<a rel="popover" ...>` would match
4. `<a rel="one popover" ...>` would match

Answer (score 1):

It's a css tilde attribute selector - it matches a word anywhere in the 'rel' attriute, regardless of order.

Maybe this is helpful:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200008b.html